Actualización al getServerSideProps en Next.js
Tengo dudas al usar getServerSideProps, cuando lo uso para recuperar data desde el lado del servidor y luego mandar esa data al componente del lado del cliente, funciona, es decir la data llega y se pinta en la tabla, pero cuando se agrega un nuevo elemento a la tabla es como si esta tabla nunca se actualizara. Por ejemplo, al inicio mi tabla tenía 72 elementos o filas, luego agregué y ahora serían 73, pero por alguna razón no se pinta ese nuevo dato, por más que recargue la página manualmente. El dato que menciono que agregué, si se agregó, ya lo verifiqué en firebase. Intenté hacer esto por que tenía toda esa lógica de llamar a la api del lado del cliente pero se sentía lento. Ahora no sé qué estoy haciendo mal.
Código relevante:
src -> app -> [lang] -> enterprise -> page.tsx
File: page.tsx
// 'use client'

// MUI Imports
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardHeader from '@mui/material/CardHeader';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

// Style Imports
import EnterpriseListTable from '@/views/apps/enterprise/list/EnterpriseListTable';
import ContentHeader from '@/components/content-header/ContentHeader';
import type { ContentHeaderProps } from '@/types/pages/utilsTypes';

// const EnterprisePage = async() => {
const EnterprisePage = async () => {

  const contentHeader: ContentHeaderProps = {
    headerTitle: 'Enterprise',
    actionButton: true,
    breadcrumb: {
      type: '',
      links: [
        {
          name: 'Enterprise',
          isLink: true,
          link: '/enterprise'
        },
      ]
    }
  };

  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/enterprise`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });

  const data = await res.json();

  console.log("WHAAAAAT: ", data?.enterprises?.length);

  const activeProductions = (id: any, dataTable: any) => {
    const enterprise = dataTable.find((x: any) => x.uid === id);

    if (!enterprise) {
      return '';
    }

    const count = enterprise.productions?.filter(
      (x: any) => x.isActive === true && !x.isExecutive
    ).length;

    return `${count}/${enterprise.maxAllowedProductions}`;
  };

  const dataMap = data.enterprises.map((enterprise: any) => {
    return {
      ...enterprise,
      count: activeProductions(enterprise.uid, data.enterprises)
    }
  })

  return (
    <>
      <ContentHeader headerTitle={contentHeader.headerTitle}
        actionButton={contentHeader.actionButton}
        breadcrumb={contentHeader.breadcrumb} />

      <Card>
        <CardHeader style={{ borderStyle: 'none' }} sx={{
          paddingTop: '1.5rem',
          paddingRight: 0,
          paddingBottom: 0,
          paddingLeft: '1.5rem',
          '& .MuiCardHeader-content': {
            paddingTop: 0,
            paddingRight: 0,
            paddingBottom: 0,
            paddingLeft: 0,
          },
        }} title={<Typography variant="h5" component="div"
        >Enterprises list</Typography>} />

        <EnterpriseListTable enterprises={dataMap} />

      </Card>
    </>
  )
}

export default EnterprisePage



src -> views -> apps -> enterprise -> list -> EnterpriseListTable.tsx
File: EnterpriseListTable.tsx

'use client'

// React Imports
import { useState, useMemo } from 'react'

// Next Imports
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation'

// MUI Imports
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
import { useColorScheme } from '@mui/material/styles'
import TablePagination from '@mui/material/TablePagination'
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem'
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch'
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';

// Third-party Imports
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import classnames from 'classnames'
import { rankItem } from '@tanstack/match-sorter-utils'
import {
  createColumnHelper,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  useReactTable,
  getFilteredRowModel,
  getFacetedRowModel,
  getFacetedUniqueValues,
  getFacetedMinMaxValues,
  getPaginationRowModel,
  getSortedRowModel
} from '@tanstack/react-table'
import type { ColumnDef, FilterFn } from '@tanstack/react-table'
import type { RankingInfo } from '@tanstack/match-sorter-utils'

// Type Imports
import type { EnterprisesType, Permissions } from '@/types/apps/enterpriseTypes';
import type { Locale } from '@configs/i18n'

// Component Imports
import AddEnterpriseDrawer from './AddEnterpriseDrawer'
import OptionMenu from '@core/components/option-menu'
import TablePaginationComponent from '@components/TablePaginationComponent'
import CustomTextField from '@core/components/mui/TextField'

// Util Imports
import { getLocalizedUrl } from '@/utils/i18n'

// Style Imports
import './enterpriseListTable.css'
import tableStyles from '@core/styles/table.module.css'

// Custom Components Imports
import EnterpisePermissionsDialog from '@/components/dialogs/enterprise-permissions-dialog'
import EnterpiseDeleteDialog from '@/components/dialogs/enterprise-delete-dialog'
import LoadingTable from '@/components/loadings/loading-table/LoadingTable'

declare module '@tanstack/table-core' {
  interface FilterFns {
    fuzzy: FilterFn<unknown>
  }
  interface FilterMeta {
    itemRank: RankingInfo
  }
}

type EnterprisesTypeWithAction = EnterprisesType & {
  action?: string
}

const fuzzyFilter: FilterFn<any> = (row, columnId, value, addMeta) => {
  // Rank the item
  const itemRank = rankItem(row.getValue(columnId), value)

  // Store the itemRank info
  addMeta({
    itemRank
  })

  // Return if the item should be filtered in/out
  return itemRank.passed
}

// Column Definitions
const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<EnterprisesTypeWithAction>()

const EnterpriseListTable = ({ enterprises }: any) => {

  // States
  // const [enterprises, setEnterprises] = useState<EnterprisesType[] | undefined>(undefined);
  // const [loadingEnterprises, setLoadingEnterprises] = useState(true);
  const [creatingEnterprise, setCreatingEnterprise] = useState(false);
  const [deletingEnterprise, setDeletingEnterprise] = useState(false);
  const [savingPermissions, setSavingPermissions] = useState(false);
  const [addEnterpriseOpen, setAddEnterpriseOpen] = useState(false)
  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = useState({})
  const [globalFilter, setGlobalFilter] = useState('')
  const [permissionsDialogOpen, setPermissionsDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedPermissions, setSelectedPermissions] = useState<Permissions | null>(null);
  const [uid, setUid] = useState<string | null | undefined>(null);
  const [errorDelete, setErrorDelete] = useState('');

  const [deleteDialogOpen, setDeleteDialogOpen] = useState<{
    open: boolean;
    uid: string | null | undefined;
    name: string | null;
    code: string | null | undefined;
    isActive: boolean | null;
  }>({
    open: false,
    uid: null,
    name: null,
    code: null,
    isActive: null,
  });

  // Hooks
  const { lang: locale } = useParams()
  const { mode } = useColorScheme()

  const openPermissionsDialog = (permissions: Permissions, uid: string | undefined) => {
    setSelectedPermissions(permissions);
    setPermissionsDialogOpen(true);
    setUid(uid);

  };

  const setParametersToDelete = (parameters: {
    open: boolean,
    uid: string | null | undefined,
    name: string | null,
    code: string | null | undefined,
    isActive: boolean | null,
  }) => {

    setDeleteDialogOpen(parameters);
    setErrorDelete('');

  }

  /* const activeProductions = (id: any, dataTable: any) => {
    const enterprise = dataTable.find((x: any) => x.uid === id);

    if (!enterprise) {
      return '';
    }

    const count = enterprise.productions?.filter(
      (x: any) => x.isActive === true && !x.isExecutive
    ).length;

    return `${count}/${enterprise.maxAllowedProductions}`;
  }; */

  /*   const getEnterprises = async () => {
      setLoadingEnterprises(true);
  
      const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/enterprise`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
  
      const data = await res.json();
  
      const dataMap = data.enterprises.map((enterprise: EnterprisesType) => {
        return {
          ...enterprise,
          count: activeProductions(enterprise.uid, data.enterprises)
        }
      })
  
      setEnterprises(dataMap);
      setLoadingEnterprises(false);
  
      if (data.status === 200) {
        return data;
      }
  
      return null;
    } */

  const savePermissions = async (data: Permissions | null,
    uidEnterprise: string | null | undefined,
    uidProduction: string | null | undefined,
    uidActivation: string | null | undefined) => {

    setSavingPermissions(true);

    const request = {
      data,
      uidEnterprise: uidEnterprise,
      uidProduction: uidProduction,
      uidActivation: uidActivation
    };

    try {
      const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/permission`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(request),
      });

      // Improve it if it's possible
      if (res) {

        if (enterprises !== undefined) {
          enterprises.forEach((element: any) => {
            if (element.uid == uid) {
              if (selectedPermissions !== null) {
                element.permissions = selectedPermissions;
              }

            }
          });
        }

        Swal.fire({
          text: `Permissions have been updated!`,
          icon: "success",
          showConfirmButton: true,
        });
        setSavingPermissions(false);

        return true;

      } else {
        console.error('Error saving permissions');

        return false;
      }
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.error('Error saving permissions:', err);

      return false;
    }

  };

  /* useEffect(() => {
    getEnterprises();
  },
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    []) */

  const createEnterprise = async (enterprise: EnterprisesType) => {
    setCreatingEnterprise(true);

    try {

      const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/enterprise`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ ...enterprise })
      });

      const data = await res.json();

      if (data.status === 201) {
        setCreatingEnterprise(false);
        setAddEnterpriseOpen(false);

        // getEnterprises();

        return true;
      } else {
        setCreatingEnterprise(false);
        setAddEnterpriseOpen(false);
        Swal.fire({
          text: `An error occurred while creating the enterprise. Please try again.`,
          icon: "error",
          showConfirmButton: true,
        });

        return false;
      }

    } catch (error) {
      setCreatingEnterprise(false);
      setAddEnterpriseOpen(false);
      Swal.fire({
        text: 'An error occurred while creating the enterprise. Please try again.',
        icon: 'error',
        showConfirmButton: true,
      });

    }

  }

  const deleteEnterprise = async (idEnterprise: any) => {

    setDeletingEnterprise(true);
    setErrorDelete('');

    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/enterprise/${idEnterprise}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
    });

    const data = await res.json();

    if (data.status === 200) {
      setDeletingEnterprise(false);

      // getEnterprises();

      return true;
    } else if (data.status === 400) {
      setErrorDelete('The enterprise cannot be deleted as one or more users are using it.');
      setDeletingEnterprise(false);

      return false;
    } else {
      console.error("Error fetching enterprise:", data.message);
      setErrorDelete('Error deleting enterprise.');
      setDeletingEnterprise(false);

      return false;
    }

  };

  const showSwalChangeActive = async (data: any) => {

    Swal.fire({
      title: `${data.isActive ? "Deactivate" : "Activate"} enterprise`,
      html: `Do you want to ${data.isActive ? "deactivate" : "activate"
        } the enterprise <b>${data.name}</b>?`,
      icon: "question",
      customClass: {
        confirmButton: "btn btn-primary",
        cancelButton: "btn btn-default ml-1",
      },
      showClass: {},
      showConfirmButton: true,
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: `Yes, ${data.isActive ? "deactivate" : "activate"
        } it!`,
      cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
      showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
      preConfirm: async () => {

        let value = null;

        let request: any = {
          name: data.name,
          maxAllowedProductions: data.maxAllowedProductions,
          notificationEmail: data.notificationEmail,
          isActive: !data.isActive
        };

        if (data.isActive) {
          request = {
            name: data.name,
            maxAllowedProductions: data.maxAllowedProductions,
            notificationEmail: data.notificationEmail,
            isActive: !data.isActive,
            lastDeactivation: new Date().toISOString()
          };
        }

        const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/enterprise/${data.uid}`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(request),
        });

        const dataRes = await response.json();


        if (dataRes) {
          // getEnterprises();

          value = true;
        } else {
          value = false
        }

        return value;


      },
      allowOutsideClick: function () {
        return !Swal.isLoading();
      },
    })
      .then((response: any) => {
        if (response?.value == true) {
          Swal.fire(
            `Enterprise ${!data.isActive ? "activated" : "deactivated"}!`,
            `The enterprise has been ${!data.isActive ? "activated" : "deactivated"
            }.`,
            "success"
          );
        } else if (response?.value == false) {
          Swal.fire(
            "Sorry!",
            `Failed to ${!data.isActive ? "deactivate" : "activate"
            } the enterprise for the next reason: It's not available. Try again.`,
            "error"
          );
        } else {
          if (
            !(response?.dismiss == "cancel" || response?.dismiss == "backdrop")
          ) {
            Swal.fire(
              "Sorry!",
              `Failed to ${!data.isActive ? "deactivate" : "activate"
              } the enterprise for the next reason: ERROR (catch). Try again.`,
              "error"
            );
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log("showSwal -> Swal -> Error", error);
      });
  }

  const columns = useMemo<ColumnDef<EnterprisesTypeWithAction, any>[]>(
    () => [

      columnHelper.accessor('name', {
        header: 'Name',
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          <Link href={`/${locale}/enterprise/${row.original.uid}/productions`}>
            <Typography className='capitalize' color='primary'>
              {row.original.name}
            </Typography>
          </Link>
        )
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('key', {
        header: 'Code',
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          <Typography className='capitalize' color='text.primary'>
            {row.original.key}
          </Typography>
        )
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('isActive', {
        header: 'Active',
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          <div className='flex items-center justify-between mbs-3'>
            <Tooltip
              title={
                !row.original.isActive && row.original.lastDeactivation
                  ? `Enterprise Deactivated on ${format(new Date(row.original.lastDeactivation), 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a')}`
                  : ''
              }
              placement='bottom'
            >
              <Switch checked={row.original.isActive}

                onChange={() => showSwalChangeActive(row.original)}

                sx={{
                  '& .MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked': {
                    color: '#28c76f',
                    '&:hover': {
                      backgroundColor: 'rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.1)',
                    },
                  },
                  '& .MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked + .MuiSwitch-track': {
                    backgroundColor: '#28c76f',
                    opacity: 1,
                  },
                  '& .MuiSwitch-thumb': {
                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                  },
                }} />
            </Tooltip>
          </div>
        )
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('maxAllowedProductions', {
        header: 'Production',
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          <Typography className='capitalize' color='text.primary'>
            {row.original.count}
          </Typography>
        )
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('educational', {
        header: 'Edu',
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          <div className='container-icon-check'>
            <div className={`div-circle circle-${row.original.educational ? 'true' : 'false'}`}></div>
            <div className='container-check'>
              <div className={`icon-check-item-${row.original.educational ? 'true' : 'false'}`}></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('action', {
        header: 'Action',
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          <div className='flex items-center'>

            <OptionMenu
              iconClassName='text-[22px] text-textSecondary'
              options={[
                {
                  text: 'Edit',
                  icon: 'tabler-edit text-[22px]',
                  href: getLocalizedUrl(`enterprise/edit/${row.original.uid}`, locale as Locale),
                  linkProps: {
                    className: classnames('flex items-center bs-[40px] plb-2 pli-4 is-full gap-2 text-textSecondary')
                  }
                },
                {
                  text: 'Delete',
                  icon: 'tabler-trash text-[22px]',
                  menuItemProps: {
                    className: 'flex items-center gap-2 text-textSecondary',
                    onClick: () => setParametersToDelete({
                      open: true,
                      uid: row.original.uid,
                      name: row.original.name,
                      code: row.original.key,
                      isActive: row.original.isActive,
                    }),
                  },
                },
                {
                  divider: true,
                  dividerProps: { className: 'margin-simple' }
                },
                {
                  text: 'Permissions',
                  icon: 'tabler-shield text-[22px]',
                  menuItemProps: {
                    className: 'flex items-center gap-2 text-textSecondary',
                    onClick: () =>
                      openPermissionsDialog(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row.original.permissions)), row.original.uid),
                  },
                },
                {
                  text: 'Productions',
                  href: getLocalizedUrl(`enterprise/${row.original.uid}/productions`, locale as Locale),
                  icon: 'tabler-chevron-right text-[22px]',
                  linkProps: {
                    className: classnames('flex items-center bs-[40px] plb-2 pli-4 is-full gap-2 text-textSecondary')
                  }
                },
              ]}
            />

          </div>
        ),
        enableSorting: false
      })
    ],
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    []
  )

  const table = useReactTable({
    data: enterprises || [],
    columns,
    filterFns: {
      fuzzy: fuzzyFilter
    },
    state: {
      rowSelection,
      globalFilter
    },
    initialState: {
      pagination: {
        pageSize: 10
      }
    },
    enableRowSelection: true, //enable row selection for all rows
    // enableRowSelection: row => row.original.age > 18, // or enable row selection conditionally per row
    globalFilterFn: fuzzyFilter,
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    onGlobalFilterChange: setGlobalFilter,
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    getFacetedRowModel: getFacetedRowModel(),
    getFacetedUniqueValues: getFacetedUniqueValues(),
    getFacetedMinMaxValues: getFacetedMinMaxValues()
  })

  return (
    <>

      <div className='flex justify-between flex-col items-start md:flex-row md:items-center p-6'>
        <div className='flex items-center gap-2 mt-2 mb-2'>
          <Typography className='hidden sm:block'>Show</Typography>
          <CustomTextField
            select
            value={table.getState().pagination.pageSize}
            onChange={e => table.setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))}
            className='is-[70px]'
          >
            <MenuItem value='10'>10</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value='25'>25</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value='50'>50</MenuItem>
          </CustomTextField>
          <Typography className='hidden sm:block'>entries</Typography>
        </div>
        <div className='flex flex-col sm:flex-row is-full sm:is-auto items-start sm:items-center gap-4'>

          <Button
            variant='contained'
            startIcon={<i className='tabler-plus' />}
            onClick={() => setAddEnterpriseOpen(!addEnterpriseOpen)}
            className='mt-2 mb-2 is-full sm:is-auto'
          >
            Add
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='overflow-x-auto' style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
        {!enterprises && <LoadingTable message="Loading enterprises..." />}
        <table className={tableStyles.table}>
          <thead className={`${mode === 'dark' ? 'dark' : 'light'}`}>
            {table.getHeaderGroups().map(headerGroup => (
              <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map(header => (
                  <th key={header.id}>
                    {header.isPlaceholder ? null : (
                      <>
                        <div
                          style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}
                          className={classnames({
                            'flex items-center': header.column.getIsSorted(),
                            'cursor-pointer select-none': header.column.getCanSort()
                          })}
                          onClick={header.column.getToggleSortingHandler()}
                        >
                          {flexRender(header.column.columnDef.header, header.getContext())}
                          {{
                            asc: <i className='tabler-chevron-up text-xl' />,
                            desc: <i className='tabler-chevron-down text-xl' />
                          }[header.column.getIsSorted() as 'asc' | 'desc'] ?? null}
                        </div>
                      </>
                    )}
                  </th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          {table.getFilteredRowModel().rows.length === 0 ? (
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td colSpan={table.getVisibleFlatColumns().length} className='text-center'>
                  No data available
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          ) : (
            <tbody>
              {table
                .getRowModel()
                .rows.slice(0, table.getState().pagination.pageSize)
                .map(row => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={row.id} className={classnames({ selected: row.getIsSelected() })}>
                      {row.getVisibleCells().map(cell => (
                        <td key={cell.id}>{flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}</td>
                      ))}
                    </tr>
                  )
                })}
            </tbody>
          )}
        </table>
      </div>

      {enterprises != null && <TablePagination
        component={() => <TablePaginationComponent table={table} />}
        count={table.getFilteredRowModel().rows.length}
        rowsPerPage={table.getState().pagination.pageSize}
        page={table.getState().pagination.pageIndex}
        onPageChange={(_, page) => {
          table.setPageIndex(page)
        }}
      />}

      <AddEnterpriseDrawer open={addEnterpriseOpen} handleClose={() => setAddEnterpriseOpen(false)} createEnterprise={createEnterprise} creatingEnterprise={creatingEnterprise} />
      <EnterpisePermissionsDialog
        open={permissionsDialogOpen}
        setOpen={setPermissionsDialogOpen}
        selectedPermissions={selectedPermissions}
        setSelectedPermissions={setSelectedPermissions}
        uidEnterprise={uid}
        uidProduction={undefined}
        uidActivation={undefined}
        onSave={savePermissions}
        title="Enterprise Permissions"
        savingPermissions={savingPermissions}
      />
      <EnterpiseDeleteDialog
        open={deleteDialogOpen.open}
        setOpen={(open) =>
          setDeleteDialogOpen({
            open,
            uid: deleteDialogOpen.uid,
            name: deleteDialogOpen.name,
            code: deleteDialogOpen.code,
            isActive: deleteDialogOpen.isActive,
          })
        }
        title="Delete Enterprise"
        uid={deleteDialogOpen.uid}
        name={deleteDialogOpen.name}
        code={deleteDialogOpen.code}
        isActive={deleteDialogOpen.isActive}
        deleteEnterprise={deleteEnterprise}
        deletingEnterprise={deletingEnterprise}
        errorDelete={errorDelete}
        setErrorDelete={setErrorDelete}
      />

    </>
  )
}

export default EnterpriseListTable




src -> app ->api -> enterprise -> route.ts
File: route.ts

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

import firebase from '@/libs/firebase';

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const enterprisesCollection = db.collection('enterprise');
    const enterprisesSnapshot = await enterprisesCollection.orderBy('name').get();

    const enterprises = [];

    for (const doc of enterprisesSnapshot.docs) {
      const enterpriseData = doc.data();
      const enterpriseId = doc.id;

      const productionsCollection = enterprisesCollection.doc(enterpriseId).collection('production');
      const productionsSnapshot = await productionsCollection.get();

      const productions = productionsSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }));

      const enterprise = {
        ...enterpriseData,
        uid: enterpriseId,
        maxAllowedProductions: enterpriseData?.maxAllowedProductions ?? 0,
        productions,
      };

      enterprises.push(enterprise);
    }

    return NextResponse.json({ enterprises });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching enterprises:', error);

    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Error fetching enterprises' }, { status: 500 });

  }
}


¿Qué estrategias o prácticas recomendadas puedo implementar para optimizar la carga y la interactividad de los componentes del lado del cliente en Next.js, y reducir el tiempo de respuesta de las solicitudes fetch?. Es la primera vez que uso Next.js
